# Persist MVC3 WebGrid data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a view model that contains an object containing a list and I'm outputting this list using a WebGrid.

The page can currently postback to multiple Actions which edit/add to this list. I'd like to persist this data across all postbacks so all Actions can act upon any changes past Actions have performed on the list. Is there anyway I can get the webgrid to bind to my model in the controller? Or am I required the list using another method like session/database?

Here's my code to help clear up what I mean.

I have a view model looking like this:

```
public class EggBasketViewModel {
    public Basket EggBasket { get; set; } // Contains list of eggs & other basket info
    public Egg EggToAdd { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm outputting it like this:

```
@model Basket.Models.EggBasketViewModel
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Eggs); // Eggs is my list of eggs
}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEditEggBasket")
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEditEgg")
        @grid.GetHtml()
        <p>
            <button name="button" value="submitEgg">Add Egg</button>
            <button name="button" value="submitBasket">Submit Basket</button>
        </p>

}
```

With my controller looking like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EggBasketViewModel Model, string button)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        switch (button) {
            case "submitEgg":
                return this.submitEgg(Model);
            case "submitBasket":
                return this.submitBasket(Model);
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        return View();
    }
}

public ActionResult SubmitBasket(EggBasketViewModel Model) {
    eggBasketRepository.InsertOrUpdate(Model.EggBasket);
    eggBasketRepository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult SubmitEgg(EggBasketViewModel Model) {
    Model.EggBasket.Eggs.Add(Model.EggToAdd);
    return View(Model);
}
```

I created it this way thinking the WebGrid would output data in a way the model binder would be able to bind it to my view model on POST and so persist any new Eggs using the html output by the WebGrid. Is there any way the WebGrid could output the list in a way compatible with the model binder? Or am I better off using a different method?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What data do you need to persist? Ideally provide a narrowed down version of your code to illustrate what you are trying to achieve and what problems are you encountering.

Comment: @Darin Added code to help with my explanation :)